# Filtered subgrid - createCallbackFunctionObject throwing indescript error

Tags: dynamics-crm, filtering, subgrid, dynamics-crm-365

I am attempting to create a filtered N:N subgrid with the code from [here](https://paulnieuwelaar.wordpress.com/2016/07/01/filter-nn-add-existing-lookup-dynamics-crm-2016-turbo-forms/):

This is a Dynamics 365 Online instance if that helps. The problem I am facing though is strange in that the lookup window comes up, filters perfectly, and allows me to choose items. But when I click "add" I get a general error message.

As far as I can tell everything in the code is fine but I am unclear as to how I should proceed to debug this. My initial thought is that I could start debugging in the `crmWindow.Mscrm.Utilities.createCallbackFunctionObject` function but I am unclear as to how to debug that function in the `global.ashx` file in an online environment. My thought is that within there I may be able to get an error I can use.

Any idea?

```
//filters an add existing lookup view (N:N)
function addExistingFromSubGridCustom(gridTypeCode, gridControl, crmWindow, fetch, layout, viewName) {
    var viewId = {DB2C6D94-48F2-E711-A2B6-00155D045E00}; // a dummy view ID
    var relName = gridControl.GetParameter(relName);
    var roleOrd = gridControl.GetParameter(roleOrd);

    //creates the custom view object
    var customView = {
        fetchXml: fetch,
        id: viewId,
        layoutXml: layout,
        name: viewName,
        recordType: gridTypeCode,
        Type: 0
    };

    var parentObj = crmWindow.GetParentObject(null, 0);
    var parameters = [gridTypeCode, , relName, roleOrd, parentObj];
    var callbackRef = crmWindow.Mscrm.Utilities.createCallbackFunctionObject(locAssocObjAction, crmWindow, parameters, false);


    crmWindow.LookupObjectsWithCallback(callbackRef, null, multi, gridTypeCode, 0, null, , null, null, null, null, null, null, viewId, [customView]);
}


function filterAddExistingContact(gridTypeCode, gridControl, primaryEntity) {
    debugger;

    var crmWindow = Xrm.Internal.isTurboForm() ? parent.window : window;

    var lookup = new Array();
    lookup = Xrm.Page.getAttribute(new_channel).getValue();
    if (lookup != null) {
        var name = lookup[0].name;
        var id = lookup[0].id;
        var entityType = lookup[0].entityType;
    }
    else
    {
        crmWindow.Mscrm.GridRibbonActions.addExistingFromSubGridAssociated(gridTypeCode, gridControl); //default button click function
        return;
    }


    if (primaryEntity != nxt_callreport) {
        crmWindow.Mscrm.GridRibbonActions.addExistingFromSubGridAssociated(gridTypeCode, gridControl); //default button click function
        return;
        //Mscrm.GridRibbonActions.addExistingFromSubGridAssociated(gridTypeCode, gridControl); //default button click function
        //return;
    }

    //fetch to retrieve filtered data
    var fetch = <fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false"> +
  <entity name="new_market"> +
    <attribute name="new_marketid" /> +
    <attribute name="new_name" /> +
    <attribute name="createdon" /> +
    <order attribute="new_name" descending="false" /> +
    <filter type="and"> +
              <condition attribute="new_channel" operator="eq" uiname=" + name + " uitype=" + entityType + " value=" + id + " /> +
    </filter> +
  </entity> +
</fetch>;

    //columns to display in the custom view (make sure to include these in the fetch query)
    var layout = <grid name="resultset" object="1" jump="new_name" select="1" icon="1" preview="1"> +
          <row name="result" id="new_name"> +
            <cell name="new_name" width="300" /> +
          </row> +
        </grid>;

    addExistingFromSubGridCustom(gridTypeCode, gridControl, crmWindow, fetch, layout, Filtered Markets);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Update this line:

```
var crmWindow = Xrm.Internal.isTurboForm() ? parent.window : window;
```

To

```
var crmWindow = Xrm.Internal.isTurboForm() ? top.parent.window : top.window;
```

and update:

```
crmWindow.Mscrm.Utilities.createCallbackFunctionObject(
```